# How to check the SRID of my table - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

I have tables, but I need to know what SRID has. I tried to search the web, but I can't find how. I am starting with Oracle. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Littlefoot is correct, but it will show you the SRID of only one row. There is no guarantee that all rows have the same SRID (this is something you must enforce).
So, I would drop the "where rownum = 1" clause and would use group by:

```
select s.geom.sdo_srid, count(*)  
from objekt_stup s  
group by s.geom.sdo_srid ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If that table has a column whose datatype is `SDO_GEOMETRY`:

```
SQL> desc objekt_stup
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID_STUP                                   NOT NULL NUMBER
 GEOM                                               PUBLIC.SDO_GEOMETRY   --> that's the column!
 <snip>
```

Then:

```
SQL> select s.geom.sdo_srid
  2  from objekt_stup s
  3  where rownum = 1;

GEOM.SDO_SRID
-------------
         8307

SQL>
```

---

Pay attention to table's alias; it won't work without it:

```
SQL> select geom.sdo_srid
  2  from objekt_stup
  3  where rownum = 1;
 select geom.sdo_srid
        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "GEOM"."SDO_SRID": invalid identifier


SQL>
```